# How do you derive the fifth equation of motion ( i.e. SUVAT equations)?

Tags: projectile-motion

I understand how to derive the following 4 SUVAT equations:

(1) v = u + at

---

(2) S = ut + 0.5at^2

---

(3) S = 0.5(u + v) x t

---

(4)  v^2 = u^2 = 2as

---

I understand that the 4th equation is obtained by rearranging equation **(1)** to make '**t**' the subject and subbing that into equation **(3)**. After, some manipulation you end up at the equation shown above.

However, during my mechanics class I was told that there was an extra SUVAT but that equation isn't necessary. I was wondering if anyone knows what it is and how to derive it.

Comment: Try 'Googling' SUVAT.

Answer (score 2):

Solve the first equation for $u$:
$$
u = v - at
$$
and substitute into the second:
$$
s = ut + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2
= (v - at)t + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2
= vt - at^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2
= vt + (-1 + \tfrac{1}{2})at^2
= vt - \tfrac{1}{2}at^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the five equations that you are searching are:

$$
v=at+v_0
$$
$$
s=s_0+v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2
$$
$$
s=s_0+\frac{1}{2}(v+v_0)t
$$
$$
v^2=v_0^2+2a(s-s_0)
$$
$$
s=s_0+vt-\frac{1}{2}at^2
$$

that can be found from the equation of motion for a particle moving on a straight line with constant acceleration.